# Break String/Array into smaller String/Array

Tags: arrays, string, vb6

In Oracle, the `IN` clause does not except more than 1000 entries e.g.

```
Select Name From Student Where Student_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,...1000,1001,1002,1003,...)
```

is not acceptable, it is broken down as

```
Select Name From Student Where Student_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,...1000) OR 
Student_ID IN (1001,1002,1003,...)
```

Now, i get these IDs as comma separated string i.e. `1,2,3,4,5,...1000,1001,1002,1003,...`.
What would be the faster way to break this into smaller parts?

Comment: I think breaking first into Array and then constructing the statements from Array would be costlier, Is it?

Answer (score 0):

First, identify the length of the `SELECT` statement without any data inside `IN` (lets call these comma separated numbers the IN string)

`Len ("Select Name From Student Where Student_ID IN ()")`

Now, your limit is `1000- Len ("Select...")`

Then, do `InStrRev("1,2,3,4,5...",",",limit)` to get a snipplet of the comma separated numbers from the IN string that you would insert into the `Select` and it would still be below 1000 chars). Remove the inserted snipplet from the IN string (dont forget to remove any leading commas from the IN string before repeating the loop)

Then you repeat the task until you run out of IN string. Don't forget to change your limit for the 2nd and so on runs, since they do not use a full select, but rather `OR Student_ID IN`, but the logic remains the same.